# SQL Query And SSRS Query

Tags: sql-server, ssrs-2008

Can anyone help me why this query is working fine in SSMS but not in SSRS?

```
SELECT     
    SUM(AMOUNTMST) AS 'Balance' 
FROM          
    BANKACCOUNTTRANS
WHERE      
    (ACCOUNTID IN (@Bank_AccountID)) 
    AND (DATAAREAID = 'RAS') 
    AND (TRANSDATE BETWEEN '2013-12-31 00:00:00' AND @From_Date)
GROUP BY 
    AccountID
```

Comment: You should update you question to at least explain what incorrect behavior is occurring.

Comment: Dear What I`m Trying To Say is This SQL Query Is Working Fine When I Run It In The SQL Management Studio But When I Run It In The SSRS Query Design It Gives Me Null Data

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  AccountID
       ,SUM(AMOUNTMST) AS [Balance]
FROM   BANKACCOUNTTRANS
WHERE (ACCOUNTID IN (@Bank_AccountID)) 
  AND (DATAAREAID = 'RAS') 
  AND (TRANSDATE BETWEEN '20131231' AND @From_Date)
Group By AccountID
```